# Accessing the recycle bin with the SharePoint REST API results in an error "Access is denied."

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, recycle-bin

I would like to access the recycle bin via the SharePoint REST API, but I get the following error.

```
{
  error: {
    code: '-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException',
      message: {
      lang: 'ja-JP',
        value: 'Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))'
    }
  }
}
```

I use Sites.ReadWrite.All permission.
I have confirmed that I can access Shared Documents with the same permission.

Do I need other permissions?

My HTTP request is as follows.

```
// using JavaScript HTTP request.

const response = await axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: `https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxxx/_api/site/RecycleBin`, // Error
  //url: `https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxxx/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared Documents')/Folders` // OK
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    Accept: 'application/json;odata=verbose',
    'x-RecycleBinContentAware': 'True'
  }
});
```

Comment: Did you check if you give `FullControl` or `Site Owner` permission to user and see if the API works?

Comment: Where are you writing this code, in SPFx or script editor/content editor web part or somewhere else? Are you talking about MS graph permissions (Sites.ReadWrite.All permission)? Try using Site Collection Administrator (SCA) account and it should work for you.